# Tuning Apache Spark MLlib algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, gradient-descent, confusion-matrix, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Apche Spark Mllib Logistic Regression and Linear Regression algorithms. I am using the code snippet given in the documentation. Now the problem raising while using LogisticRegressionWithSGD and LinearRegression in the latest version Spark 1.5.

Parameter values I used for **LogisticRegressionwithSGD** are

> Stepsize=0.01
>   No.of Iterations = 1000
>   minBatchFraction = 0.001

Confusion matrix with this values are

```
27821    0        
2287    0
```

And for the same data with **LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS**, confusion matrix is

```
27541   280  
1249   1038
```

I am completely clueless with the results with **LogisticRegressionWithSGD**. Can you please tell me the reason why I am not getting proper results with **LogisticRegressionWithSGD**.

Answer (score 0):

For LogisticRegressionWithSGD you need to vary the parameters so that you can achieve a better accuracy. 
The values for the parameters seem not adapted to your data. Try

```
  stepSize = 1.0
  numIterations = 1000
  miniBatchFraction = 1.0
```

Also, for optimizing LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS results, seems like for the second category that you try to predict you have a lot of false positives. As the results may largely depend on your data, ask yourself whether the data balanced or is biased? Is the quantity and quality sufficient to learn patterns? Are the attributes sufficiently well selected and normalized?